# Xamarin.Forms MediaElement portrait video stutter on Android 12 but landscape video works

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-12, xamarin-community-toolkit

We have a background video in our Xamarin.Forms application. It actually has two files: portrait video (1080x2304) for portait mode and landscape video (2304x1080) for landscape mode. They are both MP4 24 fps 4000 kbps. They video is played using Community Toolkit's MediaElement.

On Android 12, the portrait video stutters (plays for 0.5 s and then stops for 0.5 s and so on). However, the landscape video does not stutter. Both videos worked well on Android 11. I am using Google Pixel 3a.

What might be the problem?

Comment: We are not sure it caused by the code or Android 12. You could post this issue on github with code sample to check if it is bug or not. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: It's here now: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14814

Comment: Let's follow the link and wait.

Comment: FWIW, its generally best when submitting an issue, to strip the test case down to the simplest possible app that demonstrates the failure. "the project is very difficult to build by yourself," isn't going to make it easy for anyone to isolate/verify/resolve what is happening.